# Does the integral $\int_{3}^y (\log x)^{x-1}\,dx$ have a closed form?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Does $$f(y):=\int_{3}^y (\log x)^{x-1}\,dx$$ have a closed form or a simple lower bound?

$f(y)$ seems to be growing faster than exponential, does it eventually grow doubly exponentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised by the existence of a closed form.

Using numerical integration seems to show an "almost" exponential increase. I give below a few numbers you could play with
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
y & \log(f(y)) \\
 10 & 7.32838 \\
 20 & 20.5065 \\
 30 & 35.0920 \\
 40 & 50.4589 \\
 50 & 66.3612 \\
 60 & 82.6673 \\
 70 & 99.2960\\
 80 & 116.192 \\
 90 & 133.315 \\
 100 & 150.636 \\
 110 & 168.132 \\
 120 & 185.782 \\
 130 & 203.574 \\
 140 & 221.493 \\
 150 & 239.530
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using data generated for $10 \leq y \leq 500$ (stepsize = $10$), a nonlinear regression gives $$\log(f(y))=1.06325\, y^{1.08826}-8.24469 \qquad \qquad (R^2=0.999999)$$ with highly significant parameters

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -8.24469 & 0.34431 & \{-8.9378,-7.5516\} \\
 b & +1.06325 & 0.00727 & \{+1.0486,+1.0779\} \\
 c & +1.08826 & 0.00107 & \{+1.0861,+1.0904\} \\
\end{array}$$

The model seems to extrapolate quite well : for $y=1000$ the above correlation leads to a value of $1948$ while numerical integration would give $1930$.

Comment: Thank you.  Is the "almost" in the sense of "nearly", as opposed to slightly slower than exponential growth?

Comment: Yes it is "slightly" faster than exponential. I fact, I did the same regression work for $100\leq y \leq 100000$ (steps of $100$) and the power decreased to $\approx 1.05$.